# AngularJS filter ng-repeat by index?

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table and buttons inside a loop, this picture shows the results of what I get depending on the search

[image]

html

```
     <div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="x in names">
        <div class="panel panel-primary"  id= "{{ x.myIndex }}" >
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">{{ x.ID }} {{ x.Name }}
      <button ng-click="showCommentsWithID(x.ID)"  style="float: right;" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-comment"> 42</button>

                </h3>
                </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

     <table width="" border="0" ng-repeat="c in comments"  id= "{{ c.ID}}" ">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="30">{{ c.ID }}</td>
                        <td >{{ c.Comment}}</td>
                      </tr>
      </table>

        </div>
          </div>
          </div><!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
```

js

```
function ContactController($scope,$http) {
$scope.showCommentsWithID= function(myID) { 
                    var page = "mySQL.php?func=getComments&id=" + myID;
                    $http.get(page).success(function(response) {$scope.comments = response;});
        }
}
```

When I click on the comment Button I want to display the comments according to that ID.
This is working fine except that the comments are loaded to all tables and not only to the table with the right ID. In this example I clicked on ID 1 Coka Cola.
 [image]

Where do I need to apply a filter the js or html? both? ...

![enter image description here][3]stack.imgur.com/gqyPR.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply bind your `comments` with your product's id in order to make it unique for each product.

What we need to do is to add product's id to `$scope.comments` as following:

```
function ContactController($scope,$http) {
        $scope.comments = {}; // Init comments object.
        $scope.showCommentsWithID= function(myID) { 
                    var page = "mySQL.php?func=getComments&id=" + myID;
                    $http.get(page).success(function(response) {$scope.comments[myID] = response;});
        }
}
```

Then, you can simply loop through it:

```
 <table width="" border="0" ng-repeat="c in comments[x.ID]"  id= "{{ c.ID}}" ">
     <tr>
         <td width="30">{{ c.ID }}</td>
         <td >{{ c.Comment}}</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes, my $scope.names looks like this, but unfortunately it is not working. Do I need to expand the $scope.names with the comment parameter? hmmm

Comment: Please see my edited answer. It would work in the way you wanted.

Comment: i think there is still a small mistake, when I click the button I still get no results

Comment: Can't you try to change the `$scope.comments.myID = response;` to `$scope.comments[myID] = response;`? See this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UoPKUCAy7UKAM2smVrNA?p=preview), simulation of your situation. Hope that help.

Comment: console log says:  TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined

€ I changed as you said. I will look now at your Plunkr example

Comment: It seems that you didn't initialize `$scope.comments = {};` object.` at the very top of the controller.

Comment: holy moses, I forgot to set this    "$scope.comments = {}; // Init comments object."

.... ok that really stunned me.

thanks a lot